# JavaScript has uncaught Typeerror

Tags: javascript, dom-events, execution

I can execute JavaScript on a only this code in a test.php

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://loveslgirls.com/Flash Mp3 Player/project/deploy/js/swfobject.js"></script> 
    <script type="text/javascript">
  
        // JAVASCRIPT VARS
        // the path to the SWF file
        var swfPath = "http://loveslgirls.com/Flash Mp3 Player/project/deploy/preview.swf";
        //swfPath += "?t=" + Date.parse(new Date()); // uncomment this line to activate cache buster        
        
        // stage dimensions
        var stageW = 560;//560//"100%"; // minimum is 450
        var stageH = 300;//400;//"100%"; // minimum is 260
        
        
        // ATTRIBUTES
        var attributes = {};
        attributes.id = 'FlashComponent';
        attributes.name = attributes.id;
        
        // PARAMS
        var params = {};
        params.bgcolor = "#333333";
        params.allowfullscreen = "true";
        params.allowScriptAccess = "always";            
        //params.wmode = "transparent";
        

        /* FLASH VARS */
        var flashvars = {};
        
        /// if commented / delete these lines, the component will take the stage dimensions defined 
        /// above in "JAVASCRIPT SECTIONS" section or those defined in the settings xml         
        flashvars.componentWidth = stageW;
        flashvars.componentHeight = stageH;                         
        
        /// path to the content folder(where the xml files, images or video are nested)
        /// if you want to use absolute paths(like "http://example.com/images/....") then leave it empty("")
        // Also, if you want the embed code to work correctly you'll need to set the an absolute path for pathToFiles, like this: http://www.yourwebsite.dom/.../mp3gallery/
        flashvars.pathToFiles = "http://loveslgirls.com/Flash Mp3 Player/";
        flashvars.xmlPath = "project/deploy/mp3gallery/xml/settings.xml";
        flashvars.contentXMLPath = "project/deploy/mp3gallery/xml/mp3gallery.xml";
                    
        /** EMBED THE SWF**/
        swfobject.embedSWF(swfPath, attributes.id, stageW, stageH, "9.0.124", "http://loveslgirls.com/Flash Mp3 Player/project/deploy/js/expressInstall.swf", flashvars, params, attributes);

</script>

    <table width="100%" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
        <td align="center">
            
            <!-- this div will be overwritten by SWF object -->     
            <div id="FlashComponent">
                <p>In order to view this object you need Flash Player 9+ support!</p>
                <a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer">
                    <img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player"/>
                </a>
            </div>
    
        </td>
    </table>
```

but when I add this to inside a more complex php  file its not executing. It says:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: ST is not defined Uncaught TypeError: Object [object DOMWindow] has no method 'addEvent'

How add this player to my complex page ?

Comment: Without seeing the most complex page one can not really help well. But it seems like some of your code is trying to access the method addEvent which doesn't exists/declared in the global scope so my best bet would be look for that code and see from there.

Comment: When you are talking about yourself it is I not i! Edited it.

Comment: You need to show us the line of code where the error arises, and all functions that were in the call stack.

Comment: Dupe-Poster: [javascript flash player error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10350736/javascript-flash-player-error)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are calling the script before the element is on the page. Does the method you are calling handle the onload? If not you should either add the script after the element you are referencing, call it on document.ready, or add the script onload.